# Error 1 compiling using gcc in C and other errors

Tags: c

i have a program using two functions one is to insert a new node in a binary tree and the other is to print all leaves

the errors are:

In file included from tree.c:4:
tree.h:4: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

tree.h:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

tree.c:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

tree.c:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
make: *** [tree.o] Error 1

line 4 &5

```
void insert(fyllo **root,int newnum);

void print_inorder(fyllo *last);
```

line 8 and under

```
void insert(fyllo **riza,int newnum){

 fyllo *neofyllo;

  neofyllo=ALLOC(fyllo);        

  neofyllo->right=NULL;

  neofyllo->left=NULL;

  if ((*riza)==NULL){
       *riza=neofyllo;
       (*riza)->num=newnum;              
       return;
       }
  if (newnum<(*riza)->newnum) insert(&(*riza)->left,newnum);
  else insert(&(*riza)->right,newnum);    
     }
```

line 28 and under

```
void print_inorder(fyllo *riza){

     if (riza==NULL) return ;
     inorder(riza->left);
     printf("%d ",riza->num);
     inorder(riza->right);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler seems to have trouble with the `fyllo` type, make sure it is declared correctly.

Comment: it was right in front of me but i was stack and couldnt see the problem,thanks a lot!!

Comment: @user501986: Click on the arrow-up and the checkmark besides this answer, then. The arrow-up is to reward helpful answers, the checkmark to reward "The Right Answer".